# Can `K8s` start the firewalld service with `zone` set to `trusted`?

Tags: linux

Can `K8s` start the firewalld service with `zone` set to `trusted`?

I have an ICMP security vulnerability in my cluster and I need to turn on a firewall to restrict it. Can I enable the firewalld service with `zone` set to `trusted`?

I don't have a way to try it, it's a pre-live environment

Is there any way I can specify the zone as `trusted` when starting `firewall`, which is `public` by default, and it will affect K8s, or is there any other solution?

Comment: Is `K8s` a systemd service? I'm not familiarized with it.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon  Yes, thank you for helping to fix my problem, I use translation software and my `k8s` is a cluster and needs some extra ports to communicate between the `master` node and the `work` node

Comment: Don't worry, I actually understand what you say :-). (I'm not a native English speaker too, so I can be wrong when I answer in this forum). Regarding your question, I know nothing about `kubernetes` but a little bit of docker. And you want `k8s` service starts the `firewalld` service but with zone set to `trusted`, don't you?. If so then please provide (in your question) what you have in your `k8s` systemd service. I'm thinking in *overriding* that service to start `firewalld` with another `zone`

Comment: @EdgarMagallon  My `k8s` cluster has been running for a while and I need to disable `firewall` when deploying `k8s` because `k8s` needs to use multiple ports to communicate and the cluster uses `SDN` internally. I had to enable the firewall because of the vulnerability, and all I can think of is to set `zone` to `trusted` before starting the firewall, in the hope that it won't affect the `k8s` cluster. I am not sure if this is possible. Do you mean to modify the `firewalld.service` file to expect it to start from `zone`.

Comment: I tried to start `firewall ` in my own `k8s` test environment and switched from the default pubilc to `trusted` after starting, my cluster looks fine, I'm not sure if some unknown problem could happen to him

Comment: Oh, I thought `k8s` is not a service. And it seems you have resolved your question, nice ! Btw I'm not very familiarized with firewalls and networking  yet so I'm not sure if you can have *"security problems"* later (but I don't think so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For firewall zone pre-setting, I found the method here: [firewall-offline-cmd](https://firewalld.org/documentation/utilities/firewall-offline-cmd.html)

With `firewall-offline-cmd` you can set the firewall rules before firewalld is started.

Regarding the effect of starting `firewalld` on `k8s`, I have observed that the cluster nodes work fine after starting, and I think it works.I don't know if it will be a problem in the future

---

Note: If you have used `iptables` to make some `nat`, or other rules on the cluster, then turning on the firewall will make them disappear

---

My vulnerability: ICMP timestamp request response vulnerability

I tested and found that this vulnerability can be solved without starting `firewalld.service` , just add the following rules and they will take effect immediately, or maybe just add them if they are short rules. You don't need to start `firewalld`

```bash
┌──[root@vms152.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 13 -j DROP
┌──[root@vms152.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 14 -j DROP
```

Only you need to remember that you have done these configurations before, otherwise they will disappear when the system reboots

Comment: Could you please edit the answer to include the English translation?

Comment: @telometto  I'm sorry, I didn't notice the question, I used the web translation and I've revised the answer

Comment: Thank you very much.